# Is this expected behavior with << sign?

Tags: ruby

```
a = "test"
b = a
b << "test1"

puts a
puts b

b += "test2"
puts a
puts b

Output
------
$ruby main.rb
testtest1
testtest1
testtest1
testtest1test2
```

I was expecting following output.

```
test
testtest1
test
testtest1test2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b` and `a` holding the same object through your assignment `b = a`.Thus while you are modifying `b` with `b << "test1"`, it is actually the same object which is pointing by `a`.

```
a = "test"
b = a

a.object_id # => 71753220
b.object_id # => 71753220
```

Thus, I can tell you *behavior you are seeing is correct*.

Now `b += "test2"`, here you are assigning a new object to `b`.

```
b += "test2"
a.object_id # => 71753220
b.object_id # => 72602390
```

Better to read

[String#+](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-2B)

> Concatenation—Returns a new String containing other_str concatenated to str

[String#<<](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-3C-3C)

> Append—Concatenates the given object to `str`.